# Getting weekdays that falls between present day and last seven days in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, algorithm, time

I have an array of timestamps which i want to get the present day of the weekdays from the timestamp. I have the weekdays already but I'm getting all weekdays in the timestamp. (In this case all Saturdays). Please how do i get weekdays that falls within the last seven days and not all Saturdays here.

I need my result to be

[

```
"2022-01-08T05:33:11.000Z",
"2022-01-08T05:33:11.000Z"
```

]

instead of having all the Saturdays in the Array I need just within a week

Instead of having this

```
[
  2021-09-18T11:07:44.000Z,
  2021-11-06T20:43:16.000Z,
  2021-09-18T16:15:08.000Z,
  2022-01-08T05:33:11.000Z,
  2022-01-08T05:33:11.000Z
]
```

My code below

```js
const availabledates = [
  "2021-09-28 15:05:40",
  "2021-12-02 14:15:54",
  "2021-09-21 12:34:47",
  "2021-09-22 14:40:08",
  "2021-12-20 13:05:08",
  "2021-09-28 12:20:50",
  "2021-12-10 08:27:38",
  "2021-09-17 07:37:36",
  "2021-11-08 14:38:57",
  "2021-11-22 17:59:48",
  "2021-11-11 13:29:03",
  "2021-09-18 12:07:44",
  "2021-09-24 16:43:42",
  "2021-09-21 11:50:54",
  "2021-10-06 14:29:10",
  "2021-12-02 18:14:11",
  "2021-12-20 22:11:36",
  "2021-10-29 15:10:38",
  "2021-09-16 21:42:08",
  "2021-09-24 08:05:24",
  "2021-09-24 11:26:52",
  "2021-09-22 10:09:36",
  "2021-09-22 13:57:35",
  "2021-09-21 11:03:50",
  "2021-09-23 16:27:55",
  "2021-10-29 15:02:10",
  "2021-09-21 15:29:05",
  "2021-11-14 16:54:55",
  "2021-11-19 16:21:38",
  "2021-09-17 19:22:05",
  "2021-10-26 10:31:38",
  "2021-10-03 14:56:07",
  "2021-11-08 12:12:48",
  "2021-11-29 16:29:05",
  "2021-10-28 09:38:54",
  "2021-09-23 17:19:37",
  "2021-09-21 13:24:41",
  "2021-11-06 21:43:16",
  "2021-11-03 08:39:31",
  "2021-10-08 11:18:59",
  "2021-10-28 09:15:47",
  "2021-11-15 15:20:22",
  "2021-10-27 13:22:40",
  "2021-09-22 12:39:06",
  "2021-09-22 14:12:18",
  "2021-09-14 16:08:32",
  "2021-11-11 22:57:30",
  "2021-10-27 22:12:47",
  "2021-10-13 09:37:12",
  "2021-09-16 17:44:01",
  "2021-11-05 13:49:26",
  "2021-11-24 14:26:09",
  "2021-09-19 07:32:12",
  "2021-09-18 17:15:08",
  "2021-11-26 18:42:34",
  "2021-10-27 22:00:47",
  "2021-11-08 15:12:09",
  "2021-09-23 11:31:41",
  "2021-09-15 16:35:11",
  "2021-09-23 16:23:28",
  "2021-11-11 07:37:07",
  "2021-09-17 05:06:50",
  "2021-09-28 10:21:24",
  "2021-12-20 22:42:36",
  "2021-12-01 15:18:58",
  "2021-11-12 14:37:26",
  "2021-09-28 08:12:09",
  "2021-11-14 12:44:34",
  "2021-10-28 10:27:34",
  "2021-09-16 15:39:52",
  "2021-09-24 10:49:48",
  "2021-10-10 10:22:11",
  "2021-10-27 08:33:05",
  "2021-09-23 17:06:40",
  "2021-11-14 09:34:59",
  "2021-09-21 20:42:07",
  "2021-11-10 13:33:36",
  "2021-11-08 20:01:49",
  "2021-09-16 08:13:41",
  "2021-10-27 19:34:19",
  "2021-09-12 06:12:06",
  "2021-11-30 16:25:39",
  "2021-09-16 21:01:28",
  "2021-12-16 11:34:06",
  "2021-11-17 10:42:11",
  "2021-09-16 07:43:16",
  "2021-12-13 14:45:38",
  "2021-09-24 11:17:00",
  "2021-09-22 12:58:53",
  "2021-11-03 17:45:11",
  "2021-11-08 17:21:37",
  "2021-12-02 16:51:48",
  "2021-09-23 16:41:39",
  "2021-12-03 12:36:04",
  "2021-09-22 20:28:32",
  "2021-11-22 23:35:40",
  "2021-12-20 21:51:17",
  "2021-11-05 17:55:12",
  "2021-11-09 16:53:42",
  "2021-12-22 16:31:00",
  "2022-01-08 06:33:11",
 "2022-01-08 06:33:11",
];

const allsaturadys =  availabledates.map(x => new Date(x)).filter(x => x.getDay() === 6)

console.log(allsaturadys)
```

Comment: Couldn't understood what do you want to achieve. Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: I just edit the code @YashSharma

Comment: ```const allSaturdays = availabledates.map(x => new Date(x)).filter(x => x.getDay() === 6).sort().reverse(); const neededSaturdays = allSaturdays.filter(x => allSaturdays.indexOf(x) < 2)```

Comment: Thank you @YashSharma but my question is if there are more than two in the list

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Date manipulations may require one to consider timezones; however, this answer below does not take this crucial aspect into account.

```
const cd7 = new Date(); // current date minus 7 days
cd7.setDate(cd7.getDate() - 7);
const allsaturdays = availabledates
.map(x => new Date(x))
.filter(x => x.getDay() === 6 && x > cd7);
console.log(allsaturdays);
```

**Explanation**

- Calculate the date 7 days before current-date in 'cd7' (a constant).
- Filter array only when element is greater than 'cd7'